# Limit results in a datalist to improve page loading time Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html-datalist

I have a form I am working on with Angular JS. This form has multiple dropdown fields and input fields that search through datalists. These datalists and dropdown fields are being populated with data from some api's. One of the datalists is calling an api which returns ~40,000 records, so when opening up this form, this datalist with all those records causes the page to take a while to fully load. (Can't start filling out the form until everything is loaded)

Is there any way I could limit the results this datalist displays to improve loading time but still have all the records available for a user to search through?

HTML:

```
<div>
   <mat-form-field floatLabel="auto" class="frame-mat-input required">
      <mat-label style="font-size: 14px;">PRIMARY CLIENT</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" list="client" (change)="saveCode3($event)">
      <datalist id="client">
         <option *ngFor="let pc of primClient" [value]="pc">{{pc}}</option>
      </datalist>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
//Call to get clients returns 40,000+ records
  getClients() {
    this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/client').subscribe(
      response => {
        // console.log(response[0])
        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          if (response[i].Country == 'CA' && response[i].Status == 'A') {
            this.primClient.push(response[i].Name)
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }
primClient: any = [];
//Filters through datalist based on user input. Way to limit results here to improve efficiency?
public saveCode3(e: any): void {
let find = this.primClient.find((x: { name: any; }) => x?.name === e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not appropriate strategy to loading data. 
If data loading from backend takes much time, that for keeping good performance, you should consider data loading in chunks. On the backend side, the paging functionality should be implemented as well as searching strategy.
If rendering data takes the biggest part, you can use some virtual scrolling strategy, for instance from cdk library:
```<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50">       
 <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items">
   {{ item }}
 </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>```

Comment: Can you modify the backend for paging data? Or are you stuck with what you have?

Can you add anything to your backend? Say at least a second method that can be paged and return REDIS cached pages?

Comment: @AustinTFrench yes I can modify the backend.